# Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::getSwiftMailer does not exist - when run the app after upgrading from Laravel 8 to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have just upgraded my Laravel app from version 8 to 9. While running the app I am getting

**Method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::getSwiftMailer does not exist**

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer - Please read and follow the upgrade guide; this issue is discussed in detail here.

Comment: Installed both:

composer require symfony/mailgun-mailer symfony/http-client
composer require symfony/postmark-mailer symfony/http-client

still shows same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because of different installed package which required "getSwiftMailer" method. In my case it was laravel-notification-channels/facebook-poster. I updated package and the problem has gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).